# How to convert video to spatio-temporal volumes in python

Tags: python, opencv, video, image-processing, video-processing

I am doing my project in video analytics. I have to densely sample video. Sampling means converting video to spatio-temporal video volumes. I am using the python language. How can I do that in python? Is that option available in opencv or any other package? Input video sequence and desired output is shown [image: here]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the video file using

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(fileName)
```

Go over each frame:

```
while(cap.isOpened()):

    # Read frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
```

If you want you can just insert every frame to a 3D matrix to get the spatio-temporal matrix that you wanted

Comment: Thank you,Can i do it in real time video.?By 3D matrix you mean numpy array?

Comment: Yes you can do it for real time but then you don't read the frame from a file but from a device id. Look at the example http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html (Capture video from camera). And yes i mean a numpy array

Comment: @user6745741 I'm in the process of doing something similar and was curious on how you ended up initializing the frame to a spatio-temporal volume. What were your matrix dimensions based off of `frame`?

Comment: This is only half an answer. You haven't mentioned how to stack multiple frames together or an efficient way to sample a single frame. Rather you have just mentioned how to read in a video.