# Spatio-temporally sample a video

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I have a bunch of videos that I am reading in together into a numpy array. So let's say I have videos with frame size 100x100 and I have 1000 such frames. Then my numpy array would be of shape (1000, 100, 100, 3).

I want to sample the frames spatially with dimension 10x10 and temporally (that is stack consecutive 5 frames together). So the dimension of one such cuboid would be (10, 10, 15).

Then my resultant array would be of shape (20000, 10, 10, 15). Assuming no overlap spatially as well as temporally.

The output can be visualized to be something like this:

[image]  to [image]

A similar question has been asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39606892/how-to-convert-video-to-spatio-temporal-volumes-in-python) but the only solution provided explains how to read in videos.

Comment: At first glance I think the most difficult/awkward part of this would be dealing with the subarrays themselves. I remember struggling like on similar problems, but I recently discovered a few functions that do the job. In your case, [`skimage.util.view_as_blocks`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#view-as-blocks) is probably what you need.

Comment: Thanks, view_as_blocks proved to be very useful.